# Initializing a Reference Type in C++

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

I'm trying to better understand the differences between pointers and references in C++. Coming from a Java background, I was expecting references in C++ to be similar; I expected a pointer minus the pointer arithmetic. However, I have been very disappointed and, at times, confused. After some reading I thought I understood references to be pointers without pointer arithmetic and that can never be set to NULL. To test what I've learned I decided to start coding. However, I came across this problem and I do not understand why my code does not compile.

Here is what I was trying:

```
  3 void test(biNode*& bn)
  4 {
  5    string& s("another test");
  6    bn = new biNode(s);
  7    printf("Just Checking: %s\n", bn->getObject().c_str());
  8 }
  9
 10 int main()
 11 {
 12    biNode* bn;
 13    test(bn);
 14    printf("Just Checking: %s\n", bn->getObject().c_str());
 15 }
```

And here is the my 'biNode' header:

```
  1 #include <string>
  2 #include <iostream>
  3
  4 using namespace std;
  5
  6 class biNode
  7 {
  8    public:
  9       biNode(string& s);
 10       string& getObject();
 11    private:
 12       string& obj;
 13 };
```

With corresponding definitions:

```
  1 biNode::biNode(string& s) : obj(s)
  2 {}
  3 string& biNode::getObject()
  4 {
  5    return this->obj;
  6 }
```

Attempting to compile this produces the following error:

```
./test.cpp: In function `void test(biNode*&)':
./test.cpp:5: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'const char*'
```

I do not understand how 'string& s("another test");' is not valid. Can anyone explain this please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"another test"` is a temporary, as the compiler says. You need a named variable to reference (or a const reference).

Comment: I don't understand. If 'string& s("another test");' was instead 'string* s = new string("another test");', then there is no problem. Is it not the same constructor that is being called?

Comment: The class design of `biNode` is very questionable. Since the class contains a reference member, the object which is being referred to has to exist at least as long as the `biNode` instance. This adds a lot of hard to maintain coupling.

Comment: Also, forget about `new`. C++ doesn't generally use `new`. It's completely unidiomatic.

Comment: @Kerek I'm sorry, "forget about new"? How should I allocate memory from the heap then? And how is it completely unidiomatic if it is a construct of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize a non-const reference with anything but an existing object of the same type, which the reference will then alias. But your class `biNode` contains a reference member, too, and so you must only initialize a `biNode` instance with an object that exists for as least as long as the node instance itself!

Here's an example that demonstrates how you might use the `biNode` in a sane way:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello");

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        biNode bn(s);
        // more stuff
    }
}
```

A sensible version of your `test` function might look like this:

```
biNode test(std::string & s)
{
    return biNode(s);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("World");
    auto bn = test(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another rule of references you need to learn is that temporaries (rvalues) can only be bound to `const` references. Once bound, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference it has been bound to.

```
string& s("another test");
```

Here you're trying to bind an rvalue (the string literal `"another test"`) to `s` which is a non-`const` reference.

Change the line to

```
string const& s("another test");
```

and it will compile.

Also, in your example, there's no benefit of making `s` a reference type. So you could also change the line to

```
string s("another test");
```

and the code will compile and work as expected.

Comment: The resulting code is still totally broken, so I'd hesitate to call this answer good advice.

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is that 'string* s = new string("another test");' compiles fine. Why is the rvalue not an issue here?

Comment: @KerrekSB To be honest, I didn't even read the rest of the question. Those line numbers make it difficult to try the code out. Anyway, +1 to your answer.

Comment: I'll remove the line numbers in the future. I thought they would make the code more readable but did not consider their negative effect on compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The main source of confusion you seem to have is about what a reference is. In C++ a reference is an **alias** to an existing object. The reference must always refer to an object and the object it aliases is always the same (cannot be reset). To bind a reference to an object is to create an *alias* to that object. For that you first need an object of the appropriate type, with one explicit exception present in the standard: you can bind a `const` reference to a temporary (i.e. an expression that creates an object).